# Cannot find my shared library even though I have modified LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, linux, libraries

I am going crazy trying to create and use a simple shared library. When trying to run my program (my_prog) the shared library is not found.

CODE:

Makefile

```
my_test: my_lib my_prog
    @echo Done

my_lib: my_lib.cpp
    @echo Creating my_lib...
    g++ -Wall -pedantic -fPIC -c my_lib.cpp
    g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy_lib.so.0 -o libmy_lib.so.0.1 my_lib.o
    ln -fs libmy_lib.so.0.1 libmy_lib.so.0
    ln -fs libmy_lib.so.0 libmy_lib.so
    set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):$(PWD)

my_prog: my_test.cpp
    @echo Creating my_prog...
    g++ -Wall -pedantic -L. $^ -lmy_lib -o my_test

clean:
    rm -f *.o my_test libmy_lib*
```

my_lib.h

```
#ifndef MY_LIB_H
#define MY_LIB_H

#include <string>

class MyLib
{
  public:
    MyLib() {}
    std::string get_string() const;
};

#endif
```

my_lib.cpp

```
#include "my_lib.h"

std::string MyLib::get_string() const
{
    return std::string("Testing...\n");
}
```

my_test.cpp

```
#include "my_lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    MyLib lib;
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", lib.get_string().c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Creating it all:

```
my_pc [6:28pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 jocke lteli 4096 Jan 20 18:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 jocke lteli 4096 Jan 20 17:54 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke lteli  450 Jan 20 18:18 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke lteli  103 Jan 20 18:09 my_lib.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke lteli  139 Jan 20 18:09 my_lib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke lteli  137 Jan 20 18:06 my_test.cpp
my_pc [6:28pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => make
Creating my_lib...
g++ -Wall -pedantic -fPIC -c my_lib.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy_lib.so.0 -o libmy_lib.so.0.1 my_lib.o
ln -fs libmy_lib.so.0.1 libmy_lib.so.0
ln -fs libmy_lib.so.0 libmy_lib.so
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/openssl/1.0.0/RHEL64/lib64:/app/openmotif/2.3.1/lib:/home/jocke/own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test
Creating my_prog...
g++ -Wall -pedantic -L. my_test.cpp -lmy_lib -o my_test
Done
my_pc [6:28pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => ll
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 2 jocke lteli 4096 Jan 20 18:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 jocke lteli 4096 Jan 20 17:54 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke lteli  450 Jan 20 18:18 Makefile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jocke lteli   14 Jan 20 18:28 libmy_lib.so -> libmy_lib.so.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jocke lteli   16 Jan 20 18:28 libmy_lib.so.0 -> libmy_lib.so.0.1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jocke lteli 7098 Jan 20 18:28 libmy_lib.so.0.1*
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke lteli  103 Jan 20 18:09 my_lib.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke lteli  139 Jan 20 18:09 my_lib.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke lteli 2488 Jan 20 18:28 my_lib.o
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jocke lteli 8347 Jan 20 18:28 my_test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 jocke lteli  137 Jan 20 18:06 my_test.cpp
my_pc [6:28pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => ./my_test 
./my_test: error while loading shared libraries: libmy_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
my_pc [6:28pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => ldd my_test
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa43f1000)
    libmy_lib.so.0 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000000375da00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003757600000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000375c200000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003757a00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003757200000)
```

I have also tried to include the setting of LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my .cshrc.user file.
Both library and exe is 64-bit:

```
my_pc [6:36pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => file my_test
my_test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
my_pc [6:36pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => file libmy_lib.so.0.1
libmy_lib.so.0.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read your question if you took all that crap out of your shell prompt

Comment: Have you not tried `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to confirm your claim to have modified it? Because I don't think you have modified it.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` inside `make`, not in the shell, so the setting is **only valid inside make**.

Try this:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$(pwd)
$ ./my_test
```

Comment: I have tried that one too:

    my_pc [6:36pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    /app/openssl/1.0.0/RHEL64/lib64:/app/openmotif/2.3.1/lib:/home/jocke/own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test
    my_pc [6:49pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => make
    Creating my_lib...
    g++ -Wall -pedantic -fPIC -c my_lib.cpp
    g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy_lib.so.0 -o libmy_lib.so.0.1 my_lib.o
    ln -fs libmy_lib.so.0.1 libmy_lib.so.0
    ln -fs libmy_lib.so.0 libmy_lib.so
    Creating my_prog...

Comment: g++ -Wall -pedantic -L. my_test.cpp -lmy_lib -o my_test
    Done
    my_pc [6:49pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => ./my_test
    ./my_test: error while loading shared libraries: libmy_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    my_pc [6:49pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] =>

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding you? Why are you adding the program itself to the path?

Comment: I tried it exactly as you wrote and it gave me an error:

my_pc [6:56pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./my_test
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.

Comment: @Joachim I'm not adding the program to the library path, I'm running it with the new path, I'll change my answer in order to make it more clear

Comment: @Joachim do not use set in the shell (I didn't)

Comment: I must be using some other shell (I'm using tcsh) than you, that gives me an error:

my_pc [7:02pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$(pwd)
Bad : modifier in $ ($).
my_pc [7:02pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PWD
Bad : modifier in $ ($).

Comment: In C shell you need to use `setenv` to export the variable to child processes, `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PWD`

Comment: @JonathanWakely It still gives me the same error:

my_pc [7:06pm] [own_useful_programs/mom_visulaizer/my_test] => setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PWD
Bad : modifier in $ ($).

Comment: then stop using C shell, it sucks

Comment: Haha, well yes, I have heard that from here and there. Unfortunately I guess I'm stuck with it here at work :\

Comment: You can't refer to an undefined variable like that in csh, because it sucks. You will need to test if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is already set before trying to extend it (there may be an easier way, I haven't used csh in many years). Or just say `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $PWD`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that's a bad makefile. Make targets should generally result in a file with the same name as the target, and you should only create one file per target.

Create a make target for `libmy_lib.so.0.1` and another for `libmy_lib.so.0` and another for `libmylib.so`

`my_lib` is not a real target, so either declare it `.PHONY` or get rid of it.

Now in your makefile, this definitely doesn't do what you want:

```
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):$(PWD)
```

That line starts a new shell and sets an environment variable in that shell, then exits the shell - so has absolutely no effect. You cannot get `make` to create a new shell which alters the environment of make's parent process. You need to set the environment variable on the command line for it to work on the command line. You need to export the variable so that it is set in the application's environment, not just in your command-line's environment. In C shell you export a variable with `setenv foo bar` not `set foo=bar`

Try running `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $PWD` on the command-line before running the program.

An easier approach might be use to an RPATH instead of relying on LD_LIBRARY_PATH, i.e. link your application with `-Wl,-rpath,.` which will tell it to look

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make another post here with some code formatting. But how do I do it? I feel that "Answer Your Question" button is not the button to do it with.
Thanks for the clarification on targets and files. However, why is not my_lib a real target? It does create the file libmy_lib.so.0.1.

I couldn't get the `-rpath` variant to work, but typing `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $PWD` worked! Thanks a lot for that. Seems a bit weird though that you cannot use the Makefile to set the variable.

Comment: The target name should be the same as the filename created by the target, otherwise `make` can't tell when a file is out of date and needs to be rebuilt. Your makefile will _always_ rebuild the library, because `make` looks to see if a file called `my_lib` and decides it is missing and the rule for that target must be run. If you name the target correctly it will see a file with that name and can inspect it's modification time to decide if it's older than its prerequisites.

Comment: _"Seems a bit weird though that you cannot use the Makefile to set the variable. "_ No, it's totally normal, and decades old behaviour. You're running a shell, which runs `make` in a child process, which runs the shell again to run commands in child processes, the child shells are different processes to your command-line shell. A child process cannot alter its parent's environment. To allow that would be a security risk and allow extremely confusing behaviour.